# Error When Connecting Postgres Db: Server Certificate Does Not Match Host Name

Tags: linux, postgresql, ssl, database-administration

I installed Postgresql 13 to Centos 8 VM, trying to learn how to make connections secure with ssl. Though completing most of the steps and creating server and client certificates, i can't connect to my database remotely via PgAdmin with **verify-full** SSL mode. it gives an error like this:

```
server certificate for "centosnew" does not match host name "192.168.1.153"
```

"centosnew" is db's hostname and 192.168.1.153 is it's ip address . However, i can connect when i change SSL mode to **verify-ca** or **require** modes in PgAdmin.Where could i be doing wrong?

edit: My client's address is in pg_hba.conf looks like this:

```
hostssl    all             all             192.168.1.165/32        cert
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the common name in the server certificate?

Comment: it's "centosnew"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your server certificate, seems like the `IP` list doesn't include ip `192.168.1.153`. Make sure when you create server certificate you have added the Ip where it will listen. You can check if the certificate has the IP in it's list with this [link](https://certlogik.com/decoder/) paste your cetificate to decode here.

Add the Ip in your `CommonName` also.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, the server's certificate is for "centosnew", which is not the same as the host name you told it to connect to, "192.168.1.153".  So as far as the SSL certs are concerned, you have connected to a server other than the one you asked for.  Since preventing that is the entire point of "verify-full", it would be pretty weird if it just let you do it anyway.

So instead of telling it to connect to host "192.168.1.153", tell it to connect to host "centosnew", and let DNS do its job.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by adding my db server's name to "hosts" file in my client computer.